# print single date string from a dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe called swap_input, and I want to print the current 'date' to screen.

```
swap_input.loc[ind_current, 'date']
Out[26]: 
3   2016-08-31
```

How can I print  '2016-08-31' only?  The method above print the index '3', which is misleading

I tried

```
swap_input.loc[ind_current, 'date'].values
```

but gives me

```
Out[27]: array(['2016-08-31T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ind_current` must be an iterable of some sort.

Try:

```
swap_input.loc[ind_current[0], 'date']
```

Or:

```
pd.DataFrame.squeeze(swap_input.loc[ind_current, 'date'])
```

---

***explanation***
***setup***

```
swap_input = pd.DataFrame(pd.Timestamp('2016-08-31'), [3], ['date'])
ind_current = [3] # this is ind_current being an iterable of some kind

swap_input.loc[ind_current, 'date']

3   2016-08-31
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

***on the other hand***

```
swap_input = pd.DataFrame(pd.Timestamp('2016-08-31'), [3], ['date'])
ind_current = 3 # this is ind_current being a single index value
swap_input.loc[ind_current, 'date']

Timestamp('2016-08-31 00:00:00')
```

Whenever you pass an array like object to an indexer (like loc), you get an array like thing back along that dimension.

So, in your example `ind_current` is array like and `'date'` is a scalar.  Thus you get back a 1-dimensional object or a pandas series.  `squeeze` compresses dimensionality if it can.  So a single item in a one dimensional object can be squeezed to zero dimensions.

Comment: the second solution works! would you explain more on int_current must be an iterable of some sort?